# DbContext does not load any entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I am developing a simple project using Entity Framework, it used to run and load all my database before I reinstall a new copy of windows.

I was using Windows 10; SQL Server 2016; Entity Framework 6.1.3 and target .NET 4.5.2, and Visual Studio 2015.

I re-installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 and everything else.

I made a data connection to my `.mdf` file and I can read the database in my Visual Studio Server Explorer and verify that my tables are populated with all the rows.

When I run the project I have this error:

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myApp.exe but was not handled in user code"

This is happening because it is reading a list that should be populated from one of my entity attributes

My question is: when I create my `DbContext` instance, why does it not load any of the entities and their attributes?

Any idea?

**EDIT:** This is the connection string

> " Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="F:\Files\Development\C#\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NurseOfficeApp\NurseOfficeApp\DB\NurseOfficeApp.NurseOfficeContext.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

this is where I have the problem

```
private void FrmDesignAgency_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _context = new NurseOfficeContext();
     var mylist = _context.Set<Agency>().ToList();// mylist.count = 0
     ...
```

`mylist.count` shouldn't be 0

Comment: You may add reference source code to understand your question better.

Comment: What is the connection string you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions on the following URL:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

It will help you to setup your first EF application

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are susceptible to become invalid if the website is down or not working. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce the most relevant portions of the link/blog you are referring to into this post itself.